# Regular Expression for a Url javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for following string eg http:/xyx.co.in/#1 here instead of one it can be any number the host is fixed ...plz suggest i am not at all familar with the regular expression

Comment: have you at least tried anything?

Comment: [this question is off topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
http:\/xyx\.co\.in\/#\d+
```